# Extend KVM Volume

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I have this setup on KVM Host:

```
virsh # pool-info --pool pool
Name:           pool
UUID:           bb13c37c-47fe-c4a9-78a4-9c8abc7524fe
State:          running
Persistent:     yes
Autostart:      yes
Capacity:       1.64 TiB
Allocation:     712.00 GiB
Available:      963.12 GiB

virsh # vol-list --details --pool pool
Name                 Path                           Type     Capacity  Allocation
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
volume1              /dev/pool/volume1              block  192.00 GiB  192.00 GiB
volume2              /dev/pool/volume2              block  192.00 GiB  192.00 GiB
volume3              /dev/pool/volume3              block  192.00 GiB  192.00 GiB
volume4              /dev/pool/volume4              block  136.00 GiB  136.00 GiB

virsh # vol-info --pool pool volume3
Name:           volume3
Type:           block
Capacity:       192.00 GiB
Allocation:     192.00 GiB
```

I have a VM running in volume3 and the disk is almost full. Before extending the disk on the VM I suppose I have to extend the underlying Volume.

But when I try to extend volume3 to 500GB I get the following error:

```
virsh # vol-resize volume3 --capacity 500G --pool pool --allocate
error: Failed to change size of volume 'volume3' to 500G

error: invalid argument: storageVolumeResize: unsupported flags (0x1)
```

When I try to extend the volume without allocating the space I get different error:

```
virsh vol-resize volume3 --capacity 500G --pool pool
error: Failed to change size of volume 'volume3' to 500G

error: this function is not supported by the connection driver: storage pool does not support changing of volume capacity
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: I also tried blockresize, no change:

```
virsh # blockresize volume3 /dev/pool/volume3 734003200
error: Failed to resize block device '/dev/pool/volume3'
error: internal error unable to execute QEMU command 'block_resize': An undefined error has occurred
```

Comment: Where does this storage come from? How is it provisioned?

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to resize the block device using `lvresize` command, then you need to tell libvirt about the new size.

You should be able to do it this way:

```
$ lvresize -L 500G /dev/pool/volume3
$ virsh blockresize volumes3 --path /dev/pool/volume3 --size 500G
```